# module 'wafermap' has no attribute 'WaferMap'

Tags: python

I installed [Wafermap](https://github.com/cap1tan/wafermap), which is a package to map semiconductor wafers.

Trying this:

```py
import wafermap as wm

wm = wafermap.WaferMap(wafer_radius=100e-3,
```

and getting this error:

> module 'wafermap' has no attribute 'WaferMap'

could you advise?

Comment: You imported `wafermap` as the symbol `wm` but you are trying to use it as `wafermap` instead of `wm` & overwriting the imported symbol `wm` at the same time